# Window location gives a wrong encoding

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect a page in javascript. For that, I need the current url, so i'm using `window.location`.

```
string = window.location.pathname+"_ajouter_sol"+window.location.search+"&id_sol="+sol;
```

I did this way, but I tried by replacing the character with `%3D` or `%3F` and it didn't work.

In the url, I get something like :

> http://localhost/kohana-v3.3.5/index.php/environment/region_ajouter_sol%3Fid_region%3D1%26id_sol%3D1

I should I do to have the correct url please ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Running `location = location.pathname+"?_ajouter_sol"+location.search+"&id_sol=";` (a **very** similar one) won't give me any encoding problems. Running it from the console, will redirect me to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567251/window-location-gives-a-wrong-encoding?_ajouter_sol?_ajouter_sol?_ajouter_sol&id_sol=&id_sol=&id_sol=` (after running it 4 times on this page). You are probably shoving the resulting path through another function before redirection. Without a minimal verifyable (reproducible/repeatable) example, it's nearly impossible to solve this.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel So, I may have something wrong somewhere else :/

Comment: Yes. That is what it seems like. The problem isn't there. In fact, if you run `location = 'http://a/&';`, it will redirect there.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel When I do an alert of my variable, I get the right thing :/ but it's not the same in the url

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It works now, thanks

Comment: If you alert it and it is fine, then the error is elsewhere,. That "elsewhere" isn't present in the question, so, we can't help much. Can you please provide a more complete example?